# Растягивание спрайтов на кнопке Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем привет. Пытаюсь положить дизайн на кнопку, вешаю спрайт и получаю много пустого поля на кнопке(спрайт не растянулся на всю кнопку). Давно не работал в юнити, подскажите как растянуть спрайт корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Твой спрайт находится в компоненте Image, на объекте с RectTransform.
В левом верхнем углу у тебя есть область Anchor Presets. Нажми на неё и выбери растяжение(Stretch) по всей области. Далее сбрось отступы в полях Left Top Right и Bottom у RectTransform. Обрати внимание, что если изначально твой спрайт квадратный, он растянется по всей области.